# Can http url be used to download from https site

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl

I have .net applications which download files from my website and calls php scripts as well. Some download commands are fired using My.Computer.DownloadFile command. In some cases Webclient is used. If my website starts using ssl and default pages open using https then will http url links work. For e.g.

```
  My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://www.mywebsite.com/abcd.pdf", Application.StartupPath & "\abcd.pdf")
```

Whether if sites supported ssl and then also will the above work or I have to replace http with https and then only file downloads will work. For protected folders will it make a difference or not. Lastly I used web client to pass and read data from php script. In that case any changes is required or not. 
Thank you.

Comment: Try it first...

Comment: I cannot try because my new website once live with automatically have https as we are shifting to another server.

Comment: You need to set redirection rules in IIS, so that any request to http be redirected to https. After that it should work without any issues.

Comment: The server is unix based so there is no IIS.